# How to fit a page within a larger page

Tags: margins

So I'm writing a grant application, and I'd like to use the `todonotes` package.

The Australian Research Council apparently does not like the referees: We have a strict 10 page limit, but we're allowed half cm margins all the way around (horribly difficult to read - why not 11 pages and more reasonable margins?).

As I'm writing I want to use `todonotes` which puts notes to myself in the margin.  There's no room with these margins.  So I could increase the margins, but then I can't tell how long the text is.  So I'm looking for a way to enlarge the page.

I could use the geometry package to make a slightly larger page and put in larger margins so that the `\textwidth` and `\textheight` are the correct size.  But I'd like to be able to turn this off and print it out in the official size paper without having to do a lot of editing.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand: Normally, `geometry` is quite easy to use -- there's not a lot of editing involved, in my point of view

Comment: Use the **inline** option: `\todo[inline]{ Some sage comment }`. This will put the comments inside the page margins -- and completely mess with your 10 page limit, but when you turn off the comments that will be fine -- as you won't need to change your margins/page geometry. (Btw, I think that  the ARC should be *reducing* the page limits, and the associated "creative writing", rather than increasing them! :)

Comment: @andrew I agree reducing page limits would be a good idea.  I was making the point that the margins are so tiny that making it 11 pages and reasonable margins would have the same amount of text, but be much less painful to read.